# how to make my player jump only when it is on ground and not in air in Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

The code of mine lets my player jump many times like even when my player is in air it can jump. Just like a flappy bird game. I don't want this functionality.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool jumpkeywaspressed;
    private float horizontalinput;
    private Rigidbody rigidbodycomponent;
    
    
    
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rigidbodycomponent = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
            
       if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        jumpkeywaspressed = true;
    }
        
        horizontalinput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        
            
        if (jumpkeywaspressed)
    {
        rigidbodycomponent.AddForce(Vector3.up * 5, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        jumpkeywaspressed = false;
    }
        
        rigidbodycomponent.velocity = new Vector3(horizontalinput, rigidbodycomponent.velocity.y, 0);
    }
    

    
}
```

I have tried adding isGrounded, isTouchinGrounded vaiables. But it did not work.

Comment: you have to check its touching ground ...

Comment: To prevent players from jumping multiple times in the air, you can add a simple ground check. Unity provides the Physics.Raycast method that allows you to check if there is a surface underneath the player.

Answer (score 3):

After checking if space key was pressed, check if the player is touching the ground. How to detect if the player is touching ground?
You will have to use OnCollisionEnter function. It's better explained [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html)

Remember to set the tag of ground. And add new variable something like "isJumpable" or "isTouchingGround" that are booleans. To remember the ground collision.

Not only you will have to know when player is touching ground, but you also should know when player is NOT touching it. It's OnCollisionExit.

Read about them in unity docs and the idea will start forming in your head

Good luck

Comment: you do **not** *have to* use `OnCollisionEnter` .. it is one way of many ;)

Comment: Yes, derHugo. but since he is new (im assuming as he doesnt know) I think using oncollisionenter will be good for him as its not that confusing.
thank you for telling does ))